# Para que serve o virtualenv no Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Para que serve o virtualenv no Python?

Tem alguma alternativa para o não uso ou é mais aconselhável usar ele?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O virtualenv do Python é utilizado para isolar a versão do Python e das bibliotecas usadas em um determinado sistema.

Caso você não utilize o virtualenv, todas as bibliotecas necessárias para seu sistema seriam instaladas no ambiente do sistema operacional.

### Cenário

Você foi contratado para desenvolver um sistema de análise de dados pela empresa A e para isso você utilizará o Python 3.7.4 e as bibliotecas `pandas` e `numpy`.

Esta mesma empresa te contrata para montar um sistema de cadastro e você opta por utilizar o mesmo Python 3.7.4, porém, como você irá disponibilizar este sistema na intranet deles, você usa o `Flask`, `psycopg2` (para acesso ao PostgreSQL) e o `marshmallow`.

Você tem o hobby de criar jogos e resolve estudar o `pygame`, porém, a versão do Python escolhida é o 3.8.1

Um amigo pediu para você fazer um web scrapping e você resolve testar o Python 3.9. Além disso, você irá utilizar as bibliotecas `requests` e `bs4` (BeautifulSoup)

### Questões

Caso você **não** utilize virtualenv **para cada projeto**, você teria que utilizar o Python instalado no seu sistema e teria que colocar todas as bibliotecas nele. Isso causaria um problema de gerenciamento das bibliotecas.

A passagem "para cada projeto" foi grifada, pois caso você utilize um virtualenv para todos os projetos, você resolve apenas o isolamento do ambiente frente ao Python do sistema operacional, porém não resolve o gerenciamento das bibliotecas usadas e nem teria a possibilidade de usar versões de Python diferentes.

### Vantagem

Caso você use a mesma biblioteca em dois projetos diferentes e necessite fazer o upgrade dela em **um** dos projetos, isso é possível com virtualenv. O mesmo caso seria arriscado, pois você poderia "quebrar" o sistema que não necessita da atualização.

### Outros

Um ambiente virtual trabalha em conjunto com um gerenciador de pacotes. Você pode perfeitamente trabalhar com o `virtualenv` e o `pip`. Porém, existem outras soluções como o [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) e o [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)

O intuito destas duas ferramentas é gerenciar tanto a criação do ambiente virtual quanto a instalação das bibliotecas. Vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Outra ferramenta é o [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) que permite a instalação de múltiplas versões de Python no sistema operacional e, com uma simples configuração, escolher com qual você quer trabalhar.

### Em tempo

No Python 3.3 e acima vc cria o ambiente virtual com:

```
python -m venv /caminho/para/o/ambiente/virtual
```

Em versões anteriores

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv /caminho/para/o/ambiente/virtual
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Só um adendo pra quem usa Ubuntu, o módulo `venv` deve ser instalado separadamente com `apt install python3-venv` ou para versões específicas como  `python3.7-venv`, `python3.8-venv`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

O virtualenv serve para criar e gerenciar ambientes virtuais na sua maquina, ambientes virtuais são ambientes isolados para você desenvolver seu projeto, ele ira criar uma copia local e enxuta da versão do python que você está usando e ira instalar apenas nessa copia as versões das bibliotecas que você usar no seu projeto.

É bastante aconselhável usar ambientes virtuais para desenvolver, pois caso outra pessoa ou até mesmo você for desenvolver o mesmo projeto em outra maquina, irá ter acesso as versões exatas e compatíveis do python e dos módulos que você está usando no seu projeto, evitando incompatibilidades.

Você não é obrigado a trabalhar com ambientes virtuais, mas é o recomendado, você também encontrá a maioria dos projetos por aí usando ambientes virtuais.